# Security Updates for Microsoft SQL Server OLE DB Driver

Tags: sql-server, oledb, vulnerability-assessment

Actually I have silly question. If I install below update during working hours then is it occurring any interrupt ? Also I have checked release notes. But I couldn't find anything.

```
Security Updates for Microsoft SQL Server OLE DB Driver (June 2023)
```

Comment: What is the KB # for the update?

Comment: There is no KB number.

Comment: There should be one. Do you have a link to the update page? Else where are you seeing this update?

Comment: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/update-hotfixes-released-for-odbc-and-ole-db-drivers-for-sql/ba-p/3848484